# Return multiple JSON matches - Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON to search through a JSON file to match values, if there is a case were one value is present in two objects I'd like to be able to return both objects, but at the moment I only seem to be able to return the last object that the value was found in.

My JSON file:

```
{
  "Activities": {
  "Cold Drink": {
    "optional": "cup",
    "optional": "fridge",
    "required": "juice"
  },
  "Hot Drink": {
    "optional": "cup",
    "optional": "water",
    "optional": "kettle",
    "optional": "sugar",
    "required": "tea/coffee"
  }
}}
```

The code I'm using to match the values:

```
public String getCurrentActivity(String testHarnessSensor) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Attempting to get activity.");
    String currentActivity = null;
    try {
      InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/drink.json");
      JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
      jsonReader.beginObject();
      while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
        String nameRoot = jsonReader.nextName();
        if (nameRoot.equals("Activities")) {                    
          jsonReader.beginObject();                           
          while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            String activityName = jsonReader.nextName();      
            jsonReader.beginObject();                         
            while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {                   
              String n = jsonReader.nextName();
              n = jsonReader.nextString();                   
              if (testHarnessSensor.equals(n)) {              
                currentActivity = activityName;
              }
            }
            jsonReader.endObject();
          }
          jsonReader.endObject();
        }
      }
      jsonReader.endObject();
      jsonReader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    return currentActivity;
  }
```

Comment: Just make currentActivity an array and instead of `currentActivity = activityName;` use `currentActivity[i++] = activityName;`. Just make sure that you initialize `i` at the right scope level.

Comment: Is passing List<String> not okay with you?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this without being able to check it but this is the spirit of my comment.

```
public String[] getCurrentActivity(String testHarnessSensor) {
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Attempting to get activity.");
ArrayList<String> currentActivity = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
  ...
  while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
    ...                           
      while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
        ...                        
        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {                   
          String n = jsonReader.nextName();
          n = jsonReader.nextString();                   
          if (testHarnessSensor.equals(n)) {              
            currentActivity.add(activityName);
          }
        }
        ...
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
return currentActivity.toArray();
```

}